# InvalidCastException: Activator.CreateInstance w/ Generic Inheriting Type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, .net-4.0

I have a set of classes which all take part in an inheritance chain, listed at the bottom of this post, the last two types and the method following them are part of an abstract library and the first class the usage of such.

The problem I am having is upon instantiation of the `UserService` type using `Activator.CreateInstance` - with an `InvalidCastException` stopping me dead; this did used to cast OK though, so I'm probably just overlooking something that I've recently altered subtly (or stupidly).

As detailed in the method creating this instance at runtime, this is the code causing the error:

```
return (IDataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType>)Activator.CreateInstance(service);
```

However, the following code succeeds:

```
var a = new UserService();
var b = (UserService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User, UserRole>)a;
var c = (DataService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User>)b;
var d = (IDataService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User>)c;

var e = (IDataService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User>)a;
```

***Can anyone see what I can't?***

Not entirely sure what is going on here, but have a hunch it may be related to the typing of `IDataEntity`. The code for your examination, enquire if you feel you need more:

```
public class UserService
    : UserService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User, UserRole>
{
}

public class UserService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, UserType, UserRoleType>
    : DataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, UserType>
    where DataContextType : DataContext<DataConnectionProviderType>, new()
    where DataConnectionProviderType : DataConnectionProviderBase, new()
    where UserType : class, IUser<UserRoleType>, IDataEntity
    where UserRoleType : class, IUserRole, IDataEntity
{
}

public abstract class DataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType> 
    : IDataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType>
        where DataContextType : DataContext<DataConnectionProviderType>, new()
        where DataConnectionProviderType : DataConnectionProviderBase, new()
        where DataEntityType : class, IDataEntity
{
}

public interface IDataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType> : IDisposable
    where DataContextType : DataContext<DataConnectionProviderType>, new()
    where DataConnectionProviderType : DataConnectionProviderBase, new()
    where DataEntityType : class, IDataEntity
{
}

public static IDataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType>
    LoadServiceType<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType>(Type service)
    where DataContextType : DataContext<DataConnectionProviderType>, new()
    where DataConnectionProviderType : DataConnectionProviderBase, new()
    where DataEntityType : class, IDataEntity
{
    ...

    return (IDataService<DataContextType, DataConnectionProviderType, DataEntityType>)Activator.CreateInstance(service);             
}
```

**Exception Details:**

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '...UserService' to type '...IDataService'3[...DataContext,...Domain.Data.ConnectionProvider,...IDataEntity]'.`

Comment: One reason why it's hard to see what's going on is that you're ignoring .NET naming conventions... if you gave your type parameters a `T` prefix, it would be easier to tell which type arguments were also type parameters, and which were real type names...

Comment: Apologies, Jon - it was actually worse when I was using `T`, `K` et cetera so I altered as is now - one step at a time but will do that now. TBH, I didn't expect it to get so verbose; but that's no excuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're actually calling:

```
LoadServiceType<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, IDataEntity>(typeof(UserService));
```

That won't work, because it's trying to cast to

```
IDataService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, IDataEntity>
```

when `UserService` actually implements

```
IDataService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, User>
```

You'll find that if you change your test code to try to cast using `IDataEntity` as a type argument instead of `User`, it'll fail in the same way.

This is all to do with *generic variance*. It's a big topic - Eric Lippert has a [whole series of blog posts on it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) and last year I gave a talk at NDC on it... I don't know if the streaming site with the talk on is still available, but you can grab a torrent of all the talks [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1373839/NDC2010%20Sessions.torrent).

To give a very simple example, you can't cast an `IList<string>` to `IList<object>` in exactly the same way - otherwise this would compile, but have to fail at execution time:

```
IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
IList<object> objects = strings;
objects.Add(new object());
string firstString = strings[0]; // Eek!
```

Comment: Had a feeling about the `IDataEntity` malarkey. So, as per your `IList` example - regardless of the fact that `User` implements `IDataEntity`, I'm bound for failure, right? I'll test. And thanks for the links + info, much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, it would seem the constraint `where TUserType : class, IUser<TUserRoleType>, IDataEntity, new()` on `UserService<T,K,U>` prevents this: `var b = (UserService<DataContext, ConnectionProvider, IDataEntity, UserRole>)a;`. Any ideas on correcting to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I'm not really sure what the desired behaviour is. Is there any reason you can't just use `User` instead of `IDataEntity` when you call `LoadServiceType`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The idea is that we have a read-only collection of services that are loaded at runtime, where only one of them handles users but they all have common elements - the code doesn't necessarily know about `UserService`. I'm thinking of a 'reach-out' method, like a type resolver though, so utilisers can help the library out some - not so sure yet though.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: The caller doesn't know about UserService, but does it know about User?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It is only aware of `IUser`, `IUser` doesn't know of `IDataEntity` - we manually create that coupling with: `where UserType : class, IUser<UserRoleType>, IDataEntity`. Thanks for your time up to now, by the way.

Comment: Feels like the more I play with this the deeper the hole that I'm digging gets, oh no!

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Can you change the type arguments that `UserService` specifies in its inheritance? I'm afraid it's quite hard to follow exactly what's going on here, given the vast array of types involved...

Comment: I have complete control of the code, and so can change as needed if you have a suggestion - unless you simply mean format the code with `T`'s for you? I could also approach this another way if I could think of one - as from `DataService` backwards works as desired and changing the 'framework' of this to accommodate a specific `UserService` and its types seems like it might be wrong at this point. But I'm sick of writing the `UserService` class for every site.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: It would be useful to have an edited version of the question (possibly at the end of the current one rather than removing the existing context) which only used *one* type variable instead of one (as I think it's only one that's causing problems), along with a description of all the interfaces and types involved.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I've managed to correct this by removing the constraint of `IDataEntity` from `IDataService` / `DataService` (they didn't care anyway, so were applying constraints for the sake of their inheritors); `DataService` just requires the type to be a `class`, then `UserService` is free to require `IUser` as the `TDataEntityType` - wow, a mouthful, maybe not making things any clearer for you! Sorry for the delay and thanks for all the help. Your initial point addresses the key problem, and aided me in a solution - answered, thanks again. I can update the code if you think it would benefit.